# How do i count the number of elements on a given line of a file?

Tags: c

Something along the line of:

```
int n = sscanf(%s %s ...
```

it will save how many string element on a given line in int n,

the file can contain many lines with each line having many elements e.g.

```
efefefef efefef
dfefe fefef  eef efef efef efefef
efefef efefef efefe
efeefef [wdfefefef]
```

first line n = 2 ;
second line n = 6

also how should i remove brackets from strings to get thr string inside the bracket?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Presuming by 'element' you mean word, your best bet is to use `strtok` and pass it an appropriate list of terminators (which would include space, '[', ']', etc.